# How do you make sure your logs are sufficient?

Tags: interview, logging, methodology

I was in a job interview with a vp r&d today.

One of his questions went something like:

"How do you make sure your code works?"

This question struck me as a bit strange, so I explained how I debug (divide and conquer, debugger, prints, unit testing).

He then continued:

"What if the problem only comes once a day?"

I said I would use a log.

He then asked

"What would you put in the log?"

"How can you make sure that when you get the log, you would be able to find the problem quickly?"

I sat there quietly, not knowing the answer he was looking for.

The question seems over-broad to me, and I am sure with some specific context I would have been able to come up with something.

Maybe it's actually a viable question and I just have a knowledge gap, or I just don't get something…

*My question to you:*

Is there any standard methodology for logging?

What answer could he have been waiting to hear?

Comment: → [Why do interview questions make poor Software Engineering.SE questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6360/60357)

Comment: @amon I actually searched first where to ask this, and this was the best fit. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @Gulzar: not every question has a home in the SE network. Reddit may be a better place. FWIW, I would guess the interviewer wanted to hear the words "stack trace".

Comment: @Gulzar actually it would work better if you just edited out the interview part. It's a touchy issue with us. The logging question is a valid one.

Comment: @candied_orange: IMHO even without the interview part, the question is way too broad (and your answer, as a consequence, way too vague - no offense, just my opinion).

Comment: @DocBrown none taken. But I do think knowing the critical principles behind designing a good logging system is very much on topic. Sorry if I'm just hearing the question I want to hear. I've spent a lot of time fixing poorly thought out and overly ambitious logging systems.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I once got the question "How do you make sure your code works?"  My answer: "I test it."  They weren't impressed.

Comment: FWIW, I never debug (not for 20 years) and very, very rarely use tracing. If there is a problem, figure out the bit of code that must be causing the problem then stare at the code until you figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: @GeorgeBarwood I presume you mean you don't use a debugging tool. I've debugged code while staring at the tile in my shower.

Comment: @GeorgeBarwood: A fair observation, if you're the only one writing the code.

Comment: By the way, it may very well be that this interview question was meant to be open-ended, to see how you reasoned and what tools you had in your mental toolbox. I think another answer the interviewer might have been looking for is "the app is monitored in production, and alarm notifications are triggered under certain conditions, so I recieve an email/slack notification when the app misbehaves or has too many errors, ensuring a prompt response". The problem with logs is that they aren't useful for real time monitoring -- and neither are stacktraces -- if nobody is looking at them.

Comment: @AndresF. Ah, you're taking "quickly" to mean something different than I did. Yes alarms will at least get eyes on the log quickly. So long as you don't cry wolf.

Comment: The interviewer asked how you know your code works and you explained how you debug.  This person was pretty patient because that's a completely wrong answer. You debug when you know you have an issue, not when you need to know it's right.  Chances are the logging tangent was to help you get to the right answer: "testing"

Comment: @RobertHarvey 'I once got the question "How do you make sure your code works?" My answer: "I test it." They weren't impressed.' What were they looking for.  More detail?  What other answer could there be?

Comment: @JimmyJames: True story.  They didn't ask a follow-up question.  In retrospect, I suppose I could have asked them to make their question more specific.  It's probably a good thing I didn't get the job; I would have been miserable there.  They were a decidedly humorless bunch.

Comment: They are good questions that tells them how experienced you are with bug fixing. The "what-ifs" they threw at you are real world scenarios. If you can answer them with some options or even anecdotes, telling how you found the solution in a case you experienced, that would make a credible case that you dealt with these problems before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How do you make sure your logs are sufficient?

My 11th grade English teacher has the best answer for this question:

Know your audience.

Think about who will be reading this. What they will and wont know. Think about what they need.

When you log, log with intention. There should be a point to everything you capture. You should be thinking about the use cases your logs will be put to. You should have clear ideas here. Otherwise you give up and just log everything.

To much logging is worse than not enough. I've been on teams that couldn't control this and created beasts that filled up our largest hard drives every few days. Worse the torrent of data kept normal users from being able to figure out what was happening to the system.

When you log think about who you're logging for. They are your audience. Do not overwhelm them. Keep what you show them clear, brief and useful.

Conversely, insufficient logging is easy to fix. Add logging as you find you need it. This only works though if you are iteratively developing. That is, you write it, use it, learn from it, and rewrite it. Some people just call this testing.

For that to work you have to put yourself in the mind of who will use the log. This can be end users as well as maintenance programmers. Your log might inspire searches of the code base. It might inspire searches on google. Give them enough keywords that they can find appropriate results.

Also, it can be useful to know the state of the system. Sure give me a break point and a reproduceable error and I can learn that myself but I still hate seeing "File not found" with no mention of the expected file name. Give me the fully qualified name and I'll know where to put the file to fix this problem.

> "How can you make sure that when you get the log, you would be able to find the problem quickly?"

Make sure you log something that can be used in a search. You don't have to dump a full stack trace for every log entry. Not everything you log is consumed by a programmer anyway. But what you log should be something someone could look up in something.

When logging an error, a stack trace might be appropriate but logging covers more than errors. Class and method name are sometimes enough, usually right next to the date-time stamp. Even without those you can still provide a way to find what created this log entry by ensuring use of a unique word or phrase that can be found by searching the code base. I've used this one plenty.

Pro tip: don't break up the searchable phrase by word wrapping it in the source code. People aren't going to know where to put `"\n + "` in their search string.

Comment: Great *Pro tip*. Never realized it really (though I have faced that problem myself when I was searching code from an exception message)